# Remove Price Block Via Event Observer

Tags: layout, blocks, price, layout-update

I can pretty easily remove various blocks from a given page through an event observer on, for instance, the controller_action_layout_general_blocks_before action. Here is an example:

```
    $action = $observer->getEvent()->getAction();
    $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
    $update = $layout->getUpdate();

    $update->addUpdate('
        <reference name="product.info">
            <remove name="product.info.addtocart" />
        </reference>
    ');

    $layout->generateXml();
```

However, I can't find a way to remove the price block, even straight from the catalog.xml file. It seems like `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product->getPriceHtml($product)` creates the block dynamically. (I think it ultimately uses `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract->_getPriceBlock()` which is in a file I can't really override.)

My goal here is to remove the price block from catalog view pages in certain situations, but I can't seem to remove that block. Instead, it seems I have to change the template file itself, which I want to avoid doing for this particular task.

(Magento 1.9.0.1)

---

**This is the solution that I came up with Fabian Blechschmidt's help.**

*In my config.xml*

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
            <observers>
                <custom_to_html_before>
                    <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                    <method>coreBlockAbstractToHtmlBefore</method>
                </custom_to_html_before>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

*In my observer model*

```
public function coreBlockAbstractToHtmlBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    // Simple example logic
    $hidePrice = true;

    $block = $observer->getBlock();

    if (get_class($block) == 'Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View') {
        if ($hidePrice) {
            $block->getProduct()->setCanShowPrice(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are right. The block is created dynamically, so I think you have three options:

1. change the template
2. hook into `core_block_abstract_to_html_after` and remove everything from html
3. set `$this->getProduct()->getCanShowPrice()` to `false` before the price block is rendered

Comment: getCanShowPrice() seems to be a Magic Method to pulls an attribute. Wouldn't doing something like $product->setCanShowPrice() change the database, and have a chance at affecting how the product is displayed for other users?

Comment: I ended up using core_block_abstract_to_html_after, though I don't like that the server does all of the work to generate the HTML just to have it erased. Thanks.

Comment: I think it is better to use `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` and just `setCanShowPrice(false)` - after a night of thinking :)

Comment: canShowPrice is no attribute, so it is only temporary

Answer (score 1):

I nice trick to force remove a block is to set the template to empty string.
So, you can `overwrite the block class` and do something like this:

```
protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    // Simple example logic
    $hidePrice = true;
    if ($hidePrice) {
        $this->setTemplate('');
    }

    return $this;
}
```